# C++ lazy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, lazy

I'm implementing a lazy constructor in C++. The goal is that for a type `T`, `lazy<T>(args...)` returns a callable object which, when called, returns `T(args...)`.

This is what I have done so far:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

/**
 * Returns an object of type `T` constructed from `args`.
 */
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T make(Args&&... args)
{
    return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

/**
 * Wrap a value of type `T` and perfect-forward it when accessed.
 */
template<typename T>
class Forward {
public:
    Forward(T &&value) noexcept : value_(std::forward<T>(value))
    {}

    operator T()
    {
        return std::forward<T>(value_);
    }

private:
    T value_;
};

/**
 * Returns a callable object which, when called, returns
 * an object of type `T` constructed from `args`.
 */
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto lazy(Args&&... args) -> decltype(
        std::bind(
            make<T, Args...>,
            Forward<Args>(std::forward<Args>(args))...))
{
    return std::bind(
            make<T, Args...>,
            Forward<Args>(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}
```

(Contrived) Examples:

```
// rvalue arguments
auto makePtr = lazy<std::unique_ptr<int>>(new int(123));
auto ptr = makePtr();

// lvalue arguments
int *rawPtr = new int(456);
auto makePtr2 = lazy<std::unique_ptr<int>>(rawPtr);
auto ptr2 = makePtr2();
```

Can this code be improved (particularly in terms of efficiency)?

**UPDATE:** The `Forward` class is used only as arguments to `std::bind`. Rationale:

Suppose we have a type `Foo` with constructor `Foo(const std::unique_ptr<int> &)`. We can construct it by calling `make<Foo, const std::unique_ptr<int> &>(someUniquePtr)`, for example.

However, `std::bind(make<Foo, const std::unique_ptr<int> &>, someUniquePtr)()` won't work (I think), because the reference-ness of the second argument to `std::bind` will be dropped. Wrapping it inside a `std::cref` works, but for packed arguments it seems the `Forward` class is the only solution I can come up with that works for all types.

It's possible that I misinterpreted the cause of this but here is an example of what I mean: https://godbolt.org/g/8w2Msa.

Comment: what's the point of the std::forward on the operator T() -- doesn't that make it possible that _value would get moved out and no longer be accessible via further calls to operator T()?   or if T can never be an rvalue reference type, then it seems the forward is pointless.  or maybe I don't quite understand what forward does -- or maybe not exactly what operator t does

Comment: @xaxxon You are correct that "`value_` would get moved out and no longer be accessible via further calls to `operator T()`", but that's actually the point. Please see my update.

Comment: What behavior of std::bind are you trying to avoid by using your Forward class?

Comment: @xaxxon Updated. This is a convoluted solution, maybe (and I hope) there is a better way!

Comment: @xaxxon https://godbolt.org/g/VhbOhe This is when it stops working for me...maybe I miss interpreted the cause of the error?

Comment: no, I'm wrong.   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind : Otherwise, the stored argument is passed to the invocable object as an lvalue with the same cv-qualification as that of g.

Comment: @xaxxon Yeah, I just realized the cause is that `std::bind` can't pass references through. I have to use `std::ref` or `std::cref` to wrap the references but with packed arguments forwarding seems the only solution.

Comment: @xaxxon Minimal example: https://godbolt.org/g/8w2Msa

Answer (score 2):

I think you can really simplify your code with the use of lambdas.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_lazy(Args&&... args)
{
    return [=]{return T(std::move(args)...);};
}
```

Usage example:

```
#include <iostream>
class T
{
    int v;
    public:
        T(int v): v(v) {std::cout << "Building T\n";}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, T const& out) {return s << "T: " << out.v << "\n";}
};
class S
{
    int v;
    public:
        S(int v): v(v) {std::cout << "Building S\n";}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, S const& out) {return s << "S: " << out.v << "\n";}
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_lazy(Args&&... args)
{
    return [=]{return T(std::move(args)...);};
}

int main()
{
    auto lazyT = make_lazy<T>(1);
    auto lazyS = make_lazy<S>(2);

    std::cout << "Building\n";
    std::cout << lazyT() << "\n";
    std::cout << lazyS() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Does the make_lazy actually do what we expect it to do? The capture takes everything by value. (Maybe c++14 can prevent copies) + The members of the lambda are constants, so you need to make your lambda mutable in order to prevent a second copy.